# RSpec Controller Spec: expecting <"template"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I think that I am running a fairly normal spec using rspec, devise, rails 4:

```
  fit "renders the sysadmin view if user is a system_admin" do 
    user = build(:user)
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save
    user.update_attribute(:system_admin, true)
    sign_in user

    subject {get :index, format: :html}
    expect(subject).to render_template(:sysadmin)
  end
```

but no template seems to be getting rendered and I am receiving:

```
expecting <"sysadmin"> but rendering with <[]>
```

.  My best guess is that I am missing something in the interplay with devise.  I followed the code here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

for stubbing devise in this spec.

Comment: try to add [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views) at the top of the tests

Comment: Thanks Gotva, but the error does not seem to be occurring because of the response body being blank, which I believe would be solved by user in ``` render_views ```, but rather response does not seem to be rendering a view at all.

Comment: RSpec usually does not render views for controller specs and `response` is always blank by default. After `render_views` is enabled the response should have not empty body.

Comment: Old question... I am using a similar pattern now and it works well. Does the `:sysadmin` template exist for the `User`-related views?